# Liblinear not in CLASSPARH, on linux with weka

Tags: weka, libsvm

I download liblinear.1.92 from http://liblinear.bwaldvogel.de/ , put the .jar file under

```
$HOME/lib/liblinear-1.92/liblinear-1.92.jar
```

and start weka as

```
java -classpath $CLASSPATH:weka.jar:$HOME/lib/libsvm-3.16/java/libsvm.jar:$HOME/lib/liblinear-1.92/liblinear-1.92.jar weka.gui.GUIChooser
```

every thing was fine until I wanted to use liblinear classifier, weka shows "liblinear not in CLASSPATH". What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is the path correct? What version of WEKA are you using?

Comment: the path should be correct. I can use libsvm this way. I am using weka 3.6.9

Comment: Well, it *should* work the way you do it, given that all paths are corrects ... I will try this later, when I'm under Linux and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the liblinear.jar you downloaded is not the original one. The creator of that jar uses his own package structure, his classes are placed in

```
de.bwaldvoge.liblinear
```

but the standard weka classifier looks for `Linear` in

```
liblinear
```

On the bottom of bwaldvogels website that you linked, he gives a link to a [Weka wrapper](https://github.com/bwaldvogel/liblinear-weka) that points to his package.

The [Weka package manager](http://weka.wikispaces.com/How+do+I+use+the+package+manager?) is available from version 3.7.2 or later, so you have to download the developer version, since the latest stable is 3.6.9.

Then, simply start the Weka package manager and install LibLINEAR. It worked for me this way. Note, that this will create a "wekafiles" directory in $HOME.

Comment: Hi @Sentry thank you very much. I have also tried to build the wrapper with the code from git site. If I run ./package.sh then I get "./package.sh: line 3: ./build.env: No such file or directory". Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @gstar2002 Hmm, this wrapper is a mystery to me, too. I've tried building it but can't figure out how to do it. Try using the Weka package manager, I've edited my answer accordingly.